# How to load my tensorflow model with ModelCheckpoint callbacks?

Tags: deep-learning, callback, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have trained a model and save the weights using ModelCheckpoint:

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath = checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only = True,
    save_freq = 'epoch')
```

During the night while my model was training the electricity went off for some time and my computer turned off. Now I opened my Jupyter notebook and I want to load my model without training it from the beginning. How am I supposed to do this without compiling it again and just using the checkpoints? 
I also have tensorboard callbacks:

```
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(
    log_dir = 'tensorboard_logs\\'+ model_name,
    histogram_freq = 5,
    write_graph = True,
    update_freq = 'epoch')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only saved the weights of your model, you need to reconstruct the graph and then load your last checkpoint weights on it.

So you have to recreate your model and compile it.
For the next time, if you want to save the complete model, so you don't have to compile it again every time you load it, set `save_weights_only` to `False`.
It allow you to load your model with `keras.models.load_model()` and directly fit it after.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add() 
...
model.compile()
```

And then load your weights:

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_prefix)
```

and then you can use it normaly :

```
model.fit( ... )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Earlier I saved one model like this: 
model_path = "model_save\\tiny_resnet_tune"
tiny_resnet_tune.save(model_path). But the electricity went off for a few seconds and I was not able to do this. I only have the checkpoints from the model, that I saved with ModelCheckpoint. Since I am new to this field, I have a lot to learn and problem like this one give me some bad time.